# Downloads from remote server (Hostgator) work in Filezilla but any type of upload or file edit fails

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I'm trying to upload via FTP but all uploads fail for some reason. My setup is within a corporate network with strict firewall rules. I tried the same exact settings on Filezilla on my own laptop connected to an unfiltered WiFi, both uploads and downloads work without issues to my Hostgator file host. On corporate however, only downloads work. Below is the complete log:

```
2018-02-21 11:59:19 9864 1 Status: Connecting to 192.254.183.85:21...
    2018-02-21 11:59:19 9864 1 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
    2018-02-21 11:59:21 9864 1 Response: 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
    2018-02-21 11:59:21 9864 1 Response: 220-You are user number 2 of 150 allowed.
    2018-02-21 11:59:21 9864 1 Response: 220-Local time is now 10:59. Server port: 21.
    2018-02-21 11:59:21 9864 1 Response: 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
    2018-02-21 11:59:21 9864 1 Response: 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
    2018-02-21 11:59:21 9864 1 Command: USER greybox
    2018-02-21 11:59:21 9864 1 Response: 331 User greybox OK. Password required
    2018-02-21 11:59:21 9864 1 Command: PASS *******************
    2018-02-21 11:59:22 9864 1 Response: 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
    2018-02-21 11:59:22 9864 1 Command: SYST
    2018-02-21 11:59:23 9864 1 Response: 215 UNIX Type: L8
    2018-02-21 11:59:23 9864 1 Command: FEAT
    2018-02-21 11:59:23 9864 1 Response: 211-Extensions supported:
    2018-02-21 11:59:23 9864 1 Response:  EPRT
    2018-02-21 11:59:23 9864 1 Response:  IDLE
    2018-02-21 11:59:23 9864 1 Response:  MDTM
    2018-02-21 11:59:23 9864 1 Response:  SIZE
    2018-02-21 11:59:23 9864 1 Response:  MFMT
    2018-02-21 11:59:23 9864 1 Response:  REST STREAM
    2018-02-21 11:59:23 9864 1 Response:  MLST type*;size*;sizd*;modify*;UNIX.mode*;UNIX.uid*;UNIX.gid*;unique*;
    2018-02-21 11:59:23 9864 1 Response:  MLSD
    2018-02-21 11:59:23 9864 1 Response:  AUTH TLS
    2018-02-21 11:59:23 9864 1 Response:  PBSZ
    2018-02-21 11:59:23 9864 1 Response:  PROT
    2018-02-21 11:59:23 9864 1 Response:  UTF8
    2018-02-21 11:59:23 9864 1 Response:  TVFS
    2018-02-21 11:59:23 9864 1 Response:  ESTA
    2018-02-21 11:59:23 9864 1 Response:  PASV
    2018-02-21 11:59:23 9864 1 Response:  EPSV
    2018-02-21 11:59:23 9864 1 Response:  SPSV
    2018-02-21 11:59:23 9864 1 Response:  ESTP
    2018-02-21 11:59:23 9864 1 Response: 211 End.
    2018-02-21 11:59:23 9864 1 Command: OPTS UTF8 ON
    2018-02-21 11:59:24 9864 1 Response: 200 OK, UTF-8 enabled
    2018-02-21 11:59:24 9864 1 Status: Logged in
    2018-02-21 11:59:24 9864 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing...
    2018-02-21 11:59:24 9864 1 Command: PWD
    2018-02-21 11:59:25 9864 1 Response: 257 "/" is your current location
    2018-02-21 11:59:25 9864 1 Command: TYPE I
    2018-02-21 11:59:25 9864 1 Response: 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
    2018-02-21 11:59:25 9864 1 Command: PASV
    2018-02-21 11:59:26 9864 1 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,254,183,85,135,45)
    2018-02-21 11:59:26 9864 1 Command: MLSD
    2018-02-21 11:59:27 9864 1 Response: 150 Accepted data connection
    2018-02-21 11:59:27 9864 1 Response: 226-Options: -a -l 
    2018-02-21 11:59:27 9864 1 Response: 226 49 matches total
    2018-02-21 11:59:28 9864 1 Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
    2018-02-21 11:59:31 9864 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/public_html"...
    2018-02-21 11:59:31 9864 1 Command: CWD public_html
    2018-02-21 11:59:31 9864 1 Response: 250 OK. Current directory is /public_html
    2018-02-21 11:59:31 9864 1 Command: PWD
    2018-02-21 11:59:32 9864 1 Response: 257 "/public_html" is your current location
    2018-02-21 11:59:32 9864 1 Command: PASV
    2018-02-21 11:59:33 9864 1 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,254,183,85,121,111)
    2018-02-21 11:59:33 9864 1 Command: MLSD
    2018-02-21 11:59:34 9864 1 Response: 150 Accepted data connection
    2018-02-21 11:59:34 9864 1 Response: 226-Options: -a -l 
    2018-02-21 11:59:34 9864 1 Response: 226 70 matches total
    2018-02-21 11:59:34 9864 1 Status: Directory listing of "/public_html" successful
    2018-02-21 11:59:39 9864 3 Status: Connecting to 192.254.183.85:21...
    2018-02-21 11:59:39 9864 3 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
    2018-02-21 11:59:40 9864 3 Response: 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
    2018-02-21 11:59:40 9864 3 Response: 220-You are user number 2 of 150 allowed.
    2018-02-21 11:59:40 9864 3 Response: 220-Local time is now 10:59. Server port: 21.
    2018-02-21 11:59:40 9864 3 Response: 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
    2018-02-21 11:59:40 9864 3 Response: 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
    2018-02-21 11:59:40 9864 3 Command: USER greybox
    2018-02-21 11:59:41 9864 3 Response: 331 User greybox OK. Password required
    2018-02-21 11:59:41 9864 3 Command: PASS *******************
    2018-02-21 11:59:42 9864 3 Response: 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
    2018-02-21 11:59:42 9864 3 Command: OPTS UTF8 ON
    2018-02-21 11:59:42 9864 3 Response: 200 OK, UTF-8 enabled
    2018-02-21 11:59:42 9864 3 Status: Logged in
    2018-02-21 11:59:42 9864 3 Status: Starting upload of C:\Sandbox\ex1.py
    2018-02-21 11:59:42 9864 3 Command: CWD /public_html
    2018-02-21 11:59:43 9864 3 Response: 250 OK. Current directory is /public_html
    2018-02-21 11:59:43 9864 3 Command: PWD
    2018-02-21 11:59:44 9864 3 Response: 257 "/public_html" is your current location
    2018-02-21 11:59:44 9864 3 Command: TYPE A
    2018-02-21 11:59:44 9864 3 Response: 200 TYPE is now ASCII
    2018-02-21 11:59:44 9864 3 Command: PASV
    2018-02-21 11:59:45 9864 3 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,254,183,85,135,249)
    2018-02-21 11:59:45 9864 3 Command: STOR ex1.py
    2018-02-21 11:59:46 9864 3 Error: Connection closed by server
    2018-02-21 11:59:46 9864 3 Error: File transfer failed
    2018-02-21 11:59:46 9864 3 Status: Disconnected from server
    2018-02-21 11:59:46 9864 3 Status: Connecting to 192.254.183.85:21...
    2018-02-21 11:59:46 9864 3 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
    2018-02-21 11:59:48 9864 3 Response: 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
    2018-02-21 11:59:48 9864 3 Response: 220-You are user number 2 of 150 allowed.
    2018-02-21 11:59:48 9864 3 Response: 220-Local time is now 10:59. Server port: 21.
    2018-02-21 11:59:48 9864 3 Response: 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
    2018-02-21 11:59:48 9864 3 Response: 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
    2018-02-21 11:59:48 9864 3 Command: USER greybox
    2018-02-21 11:59:48 9864 3 Response: 331 User greybox OK. Password required
    2018-02-21 11:59:48 9864 3 Command: PASS *******************
    2018-02-21 11:59:49 9864 3 Response: 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
    2018-02-21 11:59:49 9864 3 Command: OPTS UTF8 ON
    2018-02-21 11:59:50 9864 3 Response: 200 OK, UTF-8 enabled
    2018-02-21 11:59:50 9864 3 Status: Logged in
    2018-02-21 11:59:50 9864 3 Status: Starting upload of C:\Sandbox\ex1.py
    2018-02-21 11:59:50 9864 3 Command: CWD /public_html
    2018-02-21 11:59:50 9864 3 Response: 250 OK. Current directory is /public_html
    2018-02-21 11:59:50 9864 3 Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/public_html"...
    2018-02-21 11:59:50 9864 3 Command: TYPE I
    2018-02-21 11:59:51 9864 3 Response: 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
    2018-02-21 11:59:51 9864 3 Command: PASV
    2018-02-21 11:59:52 9864 3 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,254,183,85,131,73)
    2018-02-21 11:59:52 9864 3 Command: MLSD
    2018-02-21 11:59:53 9864 3 Response: 150 Accepted data connection
    2018-02-21 11:59:53 9864 3 Response: 226-Options: -a -l 
    2018-02-21 11:59:53 9864 3 Response: 226 70 matches total
    2018-02-21 11:59:54 9864 3 Command: TYPE A
    2018-02-21 11:59:54 9864 3 Response: 200 TYPE is now ASCII
    2018-02-21 11:59:54 9864 3 Command: PASV
    2018-02-21 11:59:55 9864 3 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,254,183,85,136,148)
    2018-02-21 11:59:55 9864 3 Command: STOR ex1.py
    2018-02-21 11:59:55 9864 3 Error: Connection closed by server
    2018-02-21 11:59:55 9864 3 Error: File transfer failed
    2018-02-21 11:59:56 9864 3 Status: Disconnected from server
    2018-02-21 11:59:56 9864 3 Status: Connecting to 192.254.183.85:21...
    2018-02-21 11:59:56 9864 3 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
    2018-02-21 11:59:57 9864 3 Response: 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
    2018-02-21 11:59:57 9864 3 Response: 220-You are user number 2 of 150 allowed.
    2018-02-21 11:59:57 9864 3 Response: 220-Local time is now 10:59. Server port: 21.
    2018-02-21 11:59:57 9864 3 Response: 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
    2018-02-21 11:59:57 9864 3 Response: 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
    2018-02-21 11:59:57 9864 3 Command: USER greybox
    2018-02-21 11:59:58 9864 3 Response: 331 User greybox OK. Password required
    2018-02-21 11:59:58 9864 3 Command: PASS *******************
    2018-02-21 11:59:59 9864 3 Response: 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
    2018-02-21 11:59:59 9864 3 Command: OPTS UTF8 ON
    2018-02-21 11:59:59 9864 3 Response: 200 OK, UTF-8 enabled
    2018-02-21 11:59:59 9864 3 Status: Logged in
    2018-02-21 11:59:59 9864 3 Status: Starting upload of C:\Sandbox\ex1.py
    2018-02-21 11:59:59 9864 3 Command: CWD /public_html
    2018-02-21 12:00:00 9864 3 Response: 250 OK. Current directory is /public_html
    2018-02-21 12:00:00 9864 3 Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/public_html"...
    2018-02-21 12:00:00 9864 3 Command: TYPE I
    2018-02-21 12:00:01 9864 3 Response: 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
    2018-02-21 12:00:01 9864 3 Command: PASV
    2018-02-21 12:00:01 9864 3 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,254,183,85,193,28)
    2018-02-21 12:00:01 9864 3 Command: MLSD
    2018-02-21 12:00:03 9864 3 Response: 150 Accepted data connection
    2018-02-21 12:00:03 9864 3 Response: 226-Options: -a -l 
    2018-02-21 12:00:03 9864 3 Response: 226 70 matches total
    2018-02-21 12:00:03 9864 3 Command: TYPE A
    2018-02-21 12:00:04 9864 3 Response: 200 TYPE is now ASCII
    2018-02-21 12:00:04 9864 3 Command: PASV
    2018-02-21 12:00:04 9864 3 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,254,183,85,167,136)
    2018-02-21 12:00:04 9864 3 Command: STOR ex1.py
    2018-02-21 12:00:05 9864 3 Error: Connection closed by server
    2018-02-21 12:00:05 9864 3 Error: File transfer failed
```

Comment: Then the issue is the "strict firewall rules" of your corporate environment. Have you spoken with your corporate IT staff about this?

Comment: is it likely for them to prevent uploads but allow downloads? I haven't yet. What ports should normally be set open to allow uploads? Thanks.

Comment: Based on the evidence before us, the most "likely" thing is that your corporate network prevents outgoing FTP connections. Have you spoken with your IT staff about this? If this is the corporate website you are updating, then they should be able to either provide a work around or open the necessary ports in the firewall. If this is your own website, why are you expecting to be able to work on it at work?

Comment: It's a side project for the same company. Haven't asked to have firewall ports open yet as I was trying to use as little resources as possible, and the request is gonna take some time to be approved if ever I decided to open it up. If the firewall is indeed what is preventing the outgoing connection, then I can live with it. There are alternatives. I was hoping that posting this question might get me a solution by changing some configuration in FileZilla for example.

Comment: If it's a project of the company, then IT needs to be involved. If they don't want to change the firewall rules, then changes would have to be made on the host side. Simply adjusting your client settings would not be sufficient.

Comment: Add this as an answer so that others who have similar problems will know to check that.

Answer (score 0):

it's a late reply but corporate confirmed Passive FTP was enabled but firewall only allowed a handful of destination ports for active mode transfers. I created a web portal with a little PHP for file uploads to go through HTTP to my web server as a workaround